# is there any way of going back to searched results page from detail page while preserving the records searched?

Tags: php, javascript

i have a search form page, which takes me to reslutant page and show me so me some records acc to search criteria. And by clicking on any of the record it takes me to its details page.
now there i had placed a back button on which i had used js script history.go(-1) to go back to the resultant page while showing the same results i had searched.
but instead it 1st show "CONFORM FORM RESUBMISSION" and after i press F5 then it show me the particular records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your search results page is a POST page. By default those are not cached by the browser, which is why you get that "form resubmit" stuff - the POST has to be reperformed and the page regenerated. Changing it to a GET will eliminate that.

Comment: tnx :) but is there any other way i can do this like storing sessions etc ? and if yes then how

Comment: You could store some results in the session. Basically search form posts to a search page, which caches results in the session, then redirects to a regular page which displays those cached results. Doing a 'back' to that page would be fine, as a redirect would be a GET and could be cached.

Comment: using GET was so easy :) and solved my prob :) i love this site as i spent the whole last night to solve the prob but was not able to.

Answer (score 0):

Send you're search form data using GET , then it whont ask you to confirm form resubmission .